# Rounding floating point numbers in C++ to one decimal place

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a float number in c++ and the number can be in different forms, e.g. 355.5 or 9.9 (this is input from test code).

I have a function which is

```
float return_max(angle_set_t *angles)  
{  
    float val;  
    float max;  
    max= angles->key;  
    while( angles != NULL )  
    {  
        val= angles->key;  
        if(max<=val)  
        {  
            max=val;  
        }  
        angles = angles->right;  
    }       
    return max;
}
```

`max` can be a float value. I want to round the value to one decimal place.

I need a general solution so it works for 355.555555 and 9.999999

```
float first_aset()
{
    //do somethig
    result=return_max();
    return result;
}

void main()
{
    if( first_aset(S, 357.0, 20.0 ) != 9.9 ||
        first_aset(T, 357.0, 20.0 ) != 9.9 )
    {
         printf("Error in wrap-around interval (3)\n");
         printf(" first in interval [357, 20) in S is %f, should be 9.9\n",
         first_aset(S, 357.0, 20.0 ) );
         printf(" first in interval [357, 20) in T is %f, should be 9.9\n",
         first_aset(T, 357.0, 20.0 ) );
    }
}
```

over here is the problem..the result is:

> Error in wrap-around interval (3)
>
> first in interval [357, 20) in S is 9.900000, should be 9.9
>
> first in interval [357, 20) in T is 9.900000, should be 9.9

Comment: Do you need to round the value to display to the user, or will you perform further calculations that requires the value be rounded? Do you have a specific rounding strategy in mind? (There's more than one way to round a number.)

Comment: Why exactly do you think rounding is a good idea here? What is the significance of "one decimal digit" in this case? Why not just live with the extra precision and be happy about it?

Answer (score 9):

Do

```
answer = static_cast<float>(static_cast<int>(number * 10.)) / 10.;
```

If instead you are just trying to display the value with that precision, try [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/):

```
cout << setprecision(1) << number << endl;
```

In your code you're comparing a float to a double. This can only end badly (as will any floating point comparisons). It might (rarely) work if you compare to `9.9f`

Comment: This will definitely work fine for any number <= 360.  However, it's not technically a "general solution" because the `number * 10` part would introduce its own rounding error when applied to very large floats (since 10 is not a power of 2).

Comment: but i need it for floats not doubles.

Comment: @abbas A double is a float with more storage capacity.

Comment: @abbas: Then replace `double` with `float`. In fact, most of the time you should be using `double` unless you intend to use *lots* of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @abbas: I've replaced the word `double` with the word `float` in my answer. That should be what you need.

Comment: This rounds, when the example (9.99... going to 9.9) shows he wants to truncate.

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez: Yes, there will be some rounding errors. I'm curious, though how did you get 360 as the threshold?

Comment: @JoshD The OP's variable is named "angles", and he must be using degrees instead of radians given his sample values of 355.555555 and 9.999999

Comment: @abbas Is it possible your compiler is optimizing away the cast-within-a-cast?  Instead of what JoshD wrote, try `answer = floor(number * 10. + 0.5) / 10.;`

Comment: im not sure...what im doing is that this function is called by another function and that function returns this value to the main function..adn then I compare it with 9.9 ...wheras my function returns 9.9999999 and the comparison fails and it ERRS.

Comment: @abbas: That's a problem with the function displaying the value, not with the rounding.  9.999999999... is equal to 10.0.  @Jon: Looks to me like it's working, it rounded the value to the nearest tenth, i.e. 10.0

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez: He wants to truncate, so `answer = floor(number * 10.) / 10.;`

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - expected primary-expression before 
  ‘float’
 - ‘staic_cast’ was not declared in this 
  scope
 - expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ 
  token
 - expected ‘;’ before ‘float’

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes. This is almost certainly the case.

Comment: @abbas: That should be `static_cast` not `staic_cast`.

Comment: Its not with diplaying the value...as the comparision fails

Comment: if( first_aset(S, 357.0, 20.0 ) != 9.9 ||
       first_aset(T, 357.0, 20.0 ) != 9.9 )
   {  printf("Error in wrap-around interval (3)\n");
      printf(" first in interval [357, 20) in S is %f, should be 9.9\n",
   first_aset(S, 357.0, 20.0 ) );
      printf(" first in interval [357, 20) in T is %f, should be 9.9\n",
   first_aset(T, 357.0, 20.0 ) );
   }

Comment: first asset() uses the method in this question and then rturns the result..to the main in which I have the above test code

Comment: @abbas: You CANNOT compare floating point numbers for equality.  Floating-point numbers are inaccurate.  You need to test if the absolute value of the difference is within the acceptable error margin, e.g. `if (abs(number - 9.9) < .01)`

Comment: but the problem is that only for this instance it errors ..the rest of the floating point nubers are compared just fine

Comment: @abbas Because of how floats are represented, it is dangerous to try to compare floats using == or !=.  Instead of `(a != b)`, you should do `(fabs(a - b) > .0001)`.  See http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm

Comment: Furthermore, 9.9999999 with one decimal place isn't 9.9, it's 10.0.  The difference between 9.99999... and 10.0 is .000...0001, or in other words, zero.

Comment: but see...I cannot change the test code...also that i need 9.9 not 10.0 or 98 which the solutions above give me...i am adding interfaces to the question..maybe that might help understanding the problem

Comment: @abbas: What's the formula that's supposed to result in 9.9?  Anyway, test code that contains `if (xyz != 9.9)` is WRONG.  In C++ the literal `9.9` is inexact.

Comment: there is no ofrmula..i just updated the question ..it might clear out the confusion

Comment: @abbas: read the documents that Ben put in his answer. They should give you a better grounding upon which to understand the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Abbreviated explanation for the non-scientist: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 4):

```
rounded = truncf(original * 10) / 10;
```

However, I agree with Ben that you should definitely not be checking for exact inequality.  Use an [epsilon](http://Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems) if a comparison is needed.

Comment: Divide it by 10, too. And that will truncate rather than round... depends if that's what he wants.

Comment: will it be divide by ten for all numbers 355.55555 as well as 9.9999999

Comment: @Josh, it's pretty clear from the example he wants to truncate.

Comment: @Mathew Flaschen: Yeah, I completely misread that at first. This answer works fine.

Comment: ... but truncation using floating-point is almost certainly the wrong thing to do, because it isn't idempotent

Comment: @Ben, you're right that it's not idempotent.  The OP should explain further why he wants this.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function, looks complicated, but it is what is asked :

```
float float_one_point_round(float value)
{
        return ((float)((int)(value * 10))) / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you seem to be building your own (intrusive) linked list. C++ already provides various containers for you such as `vector` and `list`. Also, you don't have to write a function that determines the maximum value in a sequence, just use an appropriate algorithm from the standard library.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<float> angles = {0.0, 355.5, 9.9};
float maximum = *std::maximum_element(angles.begin(), angles.end());
```